# Can't get js-model to work with localStorage or at all

Tags: javascript

I am using Sammy and js-model on a small project and can't get js-model to actually work.

Here is my js-model model:

```
var Color = Model('color', function(){
    this.persistence = Model.localStorage;
});
```

Here is a route from the app that adds a new entry to the Color model. It doesn't seem to save the color entry to localStorage. When the route changes back to #/colors, there are no entries in the Color model.

```
this.get('#/colors/add', function(){
    var color_name = prompt('Color Name');
    var color_hex = prompt('Color Hex');

    var color = new Color();
    color.attr('color_name', color_name);
    color.attr('color_hex', color_hex);
    color.save();

    this.redirect('#/colors');
});
```

and finally, here is the #/colors route:

```
this.get('#/colors', function(){
    var context = {};

    context.colors = Color.all();

    load_template('assets/templates/pages/swatch.template', context, function(template, data){
        $el.html(template(data));
    });
});
```

Any advice? I am using the latest version of Chrome BTW.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for assigning persistence is slightly different (it's a method):

```
var Color = Model('color', function(){
  this.persistence(Model.localStorage);
});
```

http://benpickles.github.com/js-model/#localstorage